# connectSDK don't have a friendlyname in iOS

Tags: android, ios, live-connect-sdk

I'm using `connectSDK` and in Android I could get the friendly name but in `iOS` It don't have this thing.

I know there is a module Name but it's too general to be a "name" I'm using, Is there something i missed or any other "name" I could use ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems in Airplay there no friendly name since it's Apple private protocol. When other such as Dlna it will work.